# Deploying a camel project having no main method,web.xml

Tags: jms, weblogic, apache-camel

My project consists of a spring xml(having the camel context, weblogic configuration parameters, jms related configurations) a pojo having the route for camel (whose reference we provide in spring) and an xsl.

My project has to listen on a queue, transform the message and publish it onto another queue. Everything works fine until i try to deploy it. How do i go about deploying it...i do not have a main java class...i tested my code by invoking Main of org.apache.camel.spring.Main.

I have to deploy it onto weblogic since my route consumes from weblogic queue seamlessly. How do i do it?.jar or .war or .ear? And how do i go about creating my .jar or .war or .ear? Remember i have only 3 files in my project structure and a few dependent jars

Answer (score 1):

You will deploy it as a war file. I have not done this with Weblogic but the steps for Tomcat are listed below:

1. First make sure that all the needed jars are packaged in your war file.
2. Bootsrap Spring to your WAR file by adding the following to your web.xml

   `<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee   http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"  version="2.5">
     <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
       </listener-class>
      </listener>
    </web-app>`
3. Add location of your Spring XML file by using the following:

   `<context-param>
   <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
   <param-value>/WEB-INF/camel-context.xml</param-value>
   </context-param>`
4. Package the war with Maven i.e. run the command `mvn package`
5. Deploy the war file to the server.

Comment: Yes a WAR is a good way. See also this doc from the Apache Camel website: http://camel.apache.org/tutorial-on-using-camel-in-a-web-application.html